# solidworks, routing, pipe, diameter change

Tags: macros, solidworks

I am new with solidworks, im trying to make a macro that change the diameter of a an piece of the route i select,

i have tried recording the macro with the following instructions:

http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/SolidWorks/sldpiping/Changing_the_Diameter_of_a_Route.htm

how ever, it records nothing that i actually use.

i want to just select the piece and use the macro with a diameter i pass through code.

i have an algorithm that gives me the diameter depending of some variables, material, resistance, etc, just need to add the piece of code that may change the diameter of a selected piece of tube.

Comment: It appears there is no API call that would be the same as using the Change Route Diameter.  Have you tried recording using the Edit Route button?

Comment: yes, it is invisible on code.